# Why do I get a number in HTML after using .times on HAML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

Here is the HAML code:

```
= 10.times do
  %div
```

The HTML result is:

```html
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    10
```

Why did I get this `10` after my `div`s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`times` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Integer.html#method-i-times) returns the integer itself after executing the block the appropriate number of times, and since you are using `=` this prints the value to the output after the `div`s.

If you use [`-`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_) instead you will get the output without the final `10`:

```
- 10.times do
  %div
```